# CSS background-image

Tags: css, ionic2

I All,

I am using Ionic2. I am trying to display a message box with an image to the bottom right of it. As you can see from the screen capture below, the image (light green) is being hidden (cut-off) as soon as it is outside the message box.

[image]

**Question**

How do I get the full image to be displayed?

It is as if the `ion-list` is allowing the message box to be displayed, but not anything beyond the message box.

More info:

The image is: `/assets/message-me.png`

```css
.messages-page-content {
  > scroll-content {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .messages {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E0DAD6;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .message-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    &: : after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }
  .message {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 236px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    &.message-me {
      float: right;
      background-color: white;
      &: : before {
        right: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);
      }
    }
    &.message-you {
      float: left;
      background-color: blue;
      &: : before {
        left: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png);
      }
    }
    &.message-you::before,
    &.message-me::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 3px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 19px;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
    .message-content {
      padding: 5px 7px;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      &: : after {
        content: " \00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
        display: inline;
      }
    }
    .message-timestamp {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 2px;
      right: 17px;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: gray;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding class="messages-page-content">
  <ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="messages">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="message-item" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async">
        <div [ngClass]="{'message message-me':(item.uid == me.uid)}">
          <div [ngClass]="{'message message-you':(item.uid == you.uid)}">
            <div class="message-content">{{item.message_text}}</div>
            <span class="time-tick">
             <span class="message-timestamp">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY  h:mm a'}}</span>
            <div *ngIf="showTick(item) === true">
              <span class="checkmark">
            <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
            <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
           </span>
            </div>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

UPDATE

I did find if I changed `overflow: hidden;` below to `overflow: visible;` it fixes my problem. However, that's just in the browser, I am not sure how to change the `css` on `ion-label` in the code yet.

```
ion-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the CSS of the ion-label in your CSS, just as you said in your question:

In your CSS file, do a search for `ion-label`, and when you find the block you show, change the line of code `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: visible;`, so it looks like below:

```
ion-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or if you can't edit the CSS file, add this CSS either directly, or as a separate file:

```
ion-label {
    overflow: visible;
}
```